# Inputs for "am" and "pm" get messed up on the arabic side when editing content

Tags: i18n-l10n

When creating/editing a node on the english side all works ok but when this is done on the arabic side it breaks up the am/pm form.
The markup values also change unlike on the month or hour fields. I think this causes the content to become invalid and it prevents the node from being saved.

I'm guessing this happens with other languages that might use different characters.

Can this be corrected?

EN

```
<select class="date-ampm form-select" id="edit-field-date-und-0-value-ampm" name="field_date[und][0][value][ampm]">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="am" selected="selected">am</option>
   <option value="pm">pm</option>
</select>
```

AR

```
<select class="date-ampm form-select" id="edit-field-date-und-0-value-ampm" name="field_date[und][0][value][ampm]">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="arabic_word_for_AM" selected="selected">arabic_word_for_AM</option>
   <option value="arabic_word_for_PM">arabic_word_for_PM</option>
</select>
```

Also posted this on drupal.org that allowed the actual arabic text.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2291987

Thanks in advance for any helpful clue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation interface was translating both the value and the text on the select list. Had to change it back to latin characters and leave it as pm and am.

Unfortunately I wont be able to translate this on the node edit form but at least not the inputs don't break the form and I can save the nodes.